# add numeric value to a specific number in a list without it actually adding the numbers together

Tags: python, ascii

I am turning a string into a list of numbers (ASCII characters conversion) using ord. and then rotating each number in this list. However, if any of these numbers is less than 48 I am supposed to add the value 126 (`~` character) to number so that it prints with that dash.

This is my code so far:

`ord_list` and `chr_list` are functions I've made that turn strings into list of numbers and vice versa.

```
def encrypt_text(message: str, rotation_amount: int) -> str:
    numbers = ord_list(message)
    newnumbers = rotationlist(numbers, rotation_amount)
    for number in newnumbers:
        if number < 48:
            number = number.append(126)
    newstring = chr_string(newnumbers)
    return newstring

print(encrypt_text("(", 1))
```

When I try to print this an error keeps on coming up.

This is my input: `('(',1)` and my desired output is `'(~'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []

for number in newnumbers:
    result.append(number)
    if number < 48:
        result.append(126)
```

Simply, you can use another list rather than trying to do the tedious task of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```py
[y for x in ([n] if n >= 48 else [n, 126] for n in newnumbers) for y in x]
```